# How to join tables using SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have tables in following format
Table T1:-

```
Index A  | B  | C  |
  1   10 | 20 | 10 |
  2   15 | 45 | 42 |
  3   5  | 10 | 12 |
  :
```

Table T2:-

```
Index D  | E  |
  1   20 | 30 |
  2   35 | 5  |
  3   5  | 40 |
  :
```

Table T3:-
:
Table T4:-
:
:
Can we join multiple tables in following format using "sql" queries?

```
Index |____T1________|___T2____|...
______|_A__|_B__|_C__|_D__|_E__|
  1   | 10 | 20 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
  2   | 15 | 45 | 42 | 35 | 5  |
  3   | 5  | 10 | 12 | 5  | 40 |
  :
```

if yes, how?

Comment: use inner join to achieve this

Comment: Yes, you can. The actual keyword is `INNER JOIN` - read up [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: What does " in following format" mean? That picture does not look like a SQL table. What is your DBMS? Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple `join`:

```
select t1.index, t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t2.d, t2.e
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.index = t2.index;
```

I mean, columns can only have one name, so you don't have superheadings and subheadings.  But the data is produced by a `join`.